# Input has required but form still submits

Tags: angularjs, html

I'm using the required attribute from HTML5 validations. I don't have an idea why the form still submits even though the html5 validates the empty input field.

Here's the Plunker link. http://plnkr.co/edit/evh0fCD5hdyoXXuxJrUy

```
<form name="searchUser" ng-submit="search(username)" validation>
<input type="search" placeholder="Username" ng-minlength="1" ng-model="username" required/>
<input type="submit" value="search" ng-click="search(username)" />
</form>
```

Comment: you have an `ng-click` event on the submit button that calls `search()` so of course it will submit without validation. Also, what is the `validation` attribute you have on your `<form>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it will submit, the required attribute will only trigger the validation in the field, it wont stop the submit. For this to work you have to do something like this:

```
if($scope.searchUser.$valid){
          $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + username)
                    .then(onUserComplete, onError);

                    $scope.user = null;
  }
```

Below plnkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/XznoWH71arlV5RaDLJsd?p=preview

Hope it helps =)